# Colour legend for multiband rasters

Tags: raster, qgis-3

I've done a fair bit of searching, but cannot find anything on this.

When I export an SRTM dataset as a Geotiff from Global Mapper and bring it into QGIS 3.18.1 I need to place a colour legend bar. The legend in GM is fine (see below) but of course when I bring it into QGIS it comes in as a 3 band raster. Placing a legend in the QGIS print layout results in a legend for each band.

Is there a way to get a combined colour bar in QGIS? I'm not happy with any of the colour palettes available in QGIS if I bring it in as a single band.

[image: Colour legend from Global Mapper]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I download SRTM geotiffs ([from https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)) they arrive as single-band rasters.  Single-band makes sense because there's only one possible elevation value for each raster cell location; multiband would be superfluous.

Here's a screenshot of one of those SRTM rasters (naturally single-band) freshly downloaded and then placed into QGIS and displayed as an elevation-colored hillshade.

[image]

Somehow, additional bands have been added to your data (perhaps by Global Mapper?) that are preventing you from hillshading and coloring.  Does loading the single-band SRTM geotiff directly into QGIS without going through Global Mapper solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Stu. I can bring in the single band SRTM data ok and hillshade/colour etc. My issue is getting a colour stretch that I like. I've played around with the cpt-city ones but am yet to find one I am happy with.

Comment: Yes, selecting colors is a bit of artistic endeavour!  FWIW, my go-to cpt palette  is *Topgraphy > sd-a*.  BTW, if my answer above solved your problem, please click the check-mark icon to its left.  That lets future readers know that the question has been answered.